# Spark: All RDD data not getting saved to Cassandra table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd

**Hi, I am trying to load RDD data to a Cassandra Column family using Scala. Out of a total 50 rows , only 28 are getting stored into cassandra table.
Below is the Code snippet:**

```
val states = sc.textFile("state.txt")
//list o fall the 50 states of the USA 
var n =0 // corrected to var
val statesRDD = states.map{a => 
    n=n+1
    (n, a)
}
```

---

scala> statesRDD.count
res2: Long = 50

---

---

cqlsh:brs> CREATE TABLE BRS.state(state_id int PRIMARY KEY, state_name text);

---

statesRDD.saveToCassandra("brs","state", SomeColumns("state_id","state_name"))
**// this statement saves only 28 rows out of 50, not sure why!!!!**

```
cqlsh:brs> select * from state;

 state_id | state_name
----------+-------------
       23 |   Minnesota
        5 |  California
       28 |      Nevada
       10 |     Georgia
       16 |      Kansas
       13 |    Illinois
       11 |      Hawaii
        1 |     Alabama
       19 |       Maine
        8 |    Oklahoma
        2 |      Alaska
        4 |    New York
       18 |    Virginia
       15 |        Iowa
       22 |     Wyoming
       27 |    Nebraska
       20 |    Maryland
        7 |        Ohio
        6 |    Colorado
        9 |     Florida
       14 |     Indiana
       26 |     Montana
       21 |   Wisconsin
       17 |     Vermont
       24 | Mississippi
       25 |    Missouri
       12 |       Idaho
        3 |     Arizona

(28 rows)
```

**Can anyone please help me in finding where the issue is?**

**Edit:**

I understood why only 28 rows are getting stored in Cassandra, it's because I have made the first column a PRIMARY KEY and It looks like  in my code, n is incremented maximum to 28 and then it starts again with 1 till 22 (total 50).

```
val states = sc.textFile("states.txt")
var n =0
var statesRDD = states.map{a => 
n+=1
(n, a)
}
```

**I tried making n an accumulator variable as well(viz. val n  = sc.accumulator(0,"Counter")), but I don't see any differnce in the output.**

**scala> statesRDD.foreach(println)**
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]
(1,New Hampshire)
(2,New Jersey)
(3,New Mexico)
(4,New York)
(5,North Carolina)
(6,North Dakota)
(7,Ohio)
(8,Oklahoma)
(9,Oregon)
(10,Pennsylvania)
(11,Rhode Island)
(12,South Carolina)
(13,South Dakota)
(14,Tennessee)
(15,Texas)
(16,Utah)
(17,Vermont)
(18,Virginia)
(19,Washington)
(20,West Virginia)
(21,Wisconsin)
(22,Wyoming)
(1,Alabama)
(2,Alaska)
(3,Arizona)
(4,Arkansas)
(5,California)
(6,Colorado)
(7,Connecticut)
(8,Delaware)
(9,Florida)
(10,Georgia)
(11,Hawaii)
(12,Idaho)
(13,Illinois)
(14,Indiana)
(15,Iowa)
(16,Kansas)
(17,Kentucky)
(18,Louisiana)
(19,Maine)
(20,Maryland)
(21,Massachusetts)
(22,Michigan)
(23,Minnesota)
(24,Mississippi)
(25,Missouri)
(26,Montana)
(27,Nebraska)
(28,Nevada)

**I am curious to know what is causing n to not getting updated after value 28? Also, what are the ways in which I can create a counter which I can use for creating RDD?**

Comment: That can't be legal scala, you redefine "n" which is a val. This also will act really weird in a distributed setting if that is actually a var, since it will increment on it's own in each partition independently.

Comment: Thank you **Russell** @RussS.I was using var initially for n and would have accidentally changed it to val.
Shouldn't spark/scala interpreter be displaying an error for this, something like "Re-assignment to Val". I did not get any error :( . You can see in the results of actions.
Now, after making n a var, this looks interesting to me, the variable is getting updated maximum to a value of 28 not above that, after that it again starts with 1 till 22.
Can you give any suggestion, how can I make this code to work? I am basically trying to assign ID to each of the 50 state(1,2,3..50).

Answer (score 0):

There are some misconceptions about distributed systems embedded inside your question. The real heart of this is "How do I have a counter in a distributed system?"

The short answer is you don't. For example what you've done in your code example originally is something like this.

```
Task One {
var x = 0
record 1: x = 1
record 2: x = 2
}

Task Two {
var x = 0
record 20: x = 1
record 21: x = 2
}
```

Each machine is independently creating a new `x` variable set at 0 which gets incremented within it's own context, independently over the other nodes.

For most use cases the "counter" question can be replaced with *"How can I get a Unique Identifier per Record in a distributed system?"*

For this most users end up using a `UUID` which can be generated on independent machines with infinitesimal chances of conflicts.

If the question can be *"How can I get a monotonic increasing unique indentifier?"*

Then you can use [`zipWithUniqueIndex`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zipWithUniqueId():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,Long)]) which will not count but will generate monotonically increasing ids.

If you just want them number to start with it's best to do it on the local system.

### Edit; Why can't I use an accumulator?

Accumulators store their state (surprise) per task. You can see this with a little example:

```
val x = sc.accumulator(0, "x")
 sc.parallelize(1 to 50).foreachPartition{ it => it.foreach(y => x+= 1); println(x)}
/*
6
7
6
6
6
6
6
7
*/
x.value
// res38: Int = 50
```

The accumulators combine their state after finishing their tasks, which means you can't use them as a global distributed counter.

Comment: Thank you @RussS Yes I am new to Distributed Computing, though, I understood the concept which you explained about independent tasks.

In spark we have something called Accumulator right? Wouldn't it be treated as a counter variable?

scala> val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "Accumulator")
warning: there were two deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
accum: org.apache.spark.Accumulator[Int] = 0

scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 50).foreach(x => accum += 1)

scala> accum.value
res4: Int = 50

Comment: An accumulator is not a realtime counter.